# jQuery clear input[type=password]

Tags: jquery, input, passwords

I'm trying to clear all the inputs that are password type when jquery validation fails - I tried the following (which doesn't work) :

```
$('input[type=password]').val('');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Zwc9Q/) so perhaps there's something in your markup or some other code interfering.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with

```
$("input[type='password']").val('');
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using the [`:password`](http://api.jquery.com/password-selector/) selector as it will make your code shorter:

```
$(':password').val('');
```

Also your initial code should work. Your problem is somewhere else. Unfortunately as you haven't stated in what context and how this is called or as you haven't explained what *it doesn't work* mean I cannot help you further.

Comment: yes- sorry guys - it was in my code - sorry for unnecessary ticket - I've already flagged it as to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type^="password"]').each(function(){
    // this is an example
});
```

Answer (score 1):

short answer :

to select all password fields using jquery you can use :

```
$(':password').val('');
```

but for *better performance* in modern browsers use

```
$("input[type='password']").val('');
```

**Detailed Answer**

[**:password Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/password-selector/) *( from jQuery document )*

Description: Selects all elements of type password.

***version added: 1.0***

jQuery( ":password" )

$( ":password" ) is equivalent to $( "[type=password]" ).

As with other pseudo-class selectors (those that begin with a ":") it is recommended to precede it with a tag name or some other selector; otherwise, the universal selector ( "*" ) is implied.

In other words, the bare $( ":password" ) is equivalent to $( "*:password" ), so $( "input:password" ) should be used instead.

**Additional Notes:**

Because :password is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :password cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="password"] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
$("#id of a input field").val('');
```

Comment: That will only clear one specific field.  The question asks how to clear ALL password fields at once.